# show/hide not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table class='generic'>
<script>
$('#select_bh').click(
    function(){
        if($('#select_bh')[0].checked){
        $('#hide_box_bh_s').show();
        }
        else{
        $('#hide_box_bh_s').hide();
        }
    }
);
</script>
<tr>
    <td>
        <b><input type="checkbox" id="select_bh" name="pj_boilerhouse" value="Boiler_House"/>Boiler House</b>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span id='hide_box_bh_s' style='display:none'>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<b><input type="checkbox" class="case_bh_s" name="pj_bh_s" value="Structural"/> Structural</b>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

the show show/hide in JavaScript is not functioning.. some advice pls, thx.. some how it goes like this when i check the checkbox it will have a new row under the existing row

Comment: Well, your jQuery isn't wrapped in a `$(document).ready()`, so the event-handlers are bound to elements which aren't present in the DOM. And, incidentally, Java is ***not*** JavaScript.

Comment: Java != JavaScript. Also please read the **[jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Hello_jQuery)**: *"As almost everything we do when using jQuery reads or manipulates the document object model (DOM), we need to make sure that we start adding events etc. as soon as the DOM is ready. To do this, we register a ready event for the document."* It contains all the information to get you started.

Comment: Why do you quote in double and single quotes?  While it may work, you should be consistent (in case you ever want to parse it later).  Also, your script has no "type" and it's embedded in the document, so make sure to wrap it in the DOMReady event

Answer (score 1):

You should put your codes inside document ready handler, your code doesn't work as you have bound the event handler to an element that is not added to the DOM yet. The codes that are within the ready handler are executed after the DOM is fully loaded. Also note that *Java* is not *JavaScript*.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#select_bh').click(function(){
        $('#hide_box_bh_s').css('display', this.checked ? 'block' : 'none');
   });
})
```

I have used *conditional operator* which is a shortcut for `if` statement, if the checkbox is checked it sets the value of `display` property to `block` otherwise it sets it to `none`.

- [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
- [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)
- [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Yes. But please, look at his posted code and then consider: 'will the OP understand what this does, or how it works?' Please, could you explain?

Comment: If only the '$('#hide_box_bh_s').css('display', this.checked ? 'block' : 'none');' line is confusing then it's simple. It's changing the value set to the css display property based on the value of `this.checked`. You can think of it like an if statement. It works like this `(if) this.checked (is true) ? (set it to) 'block' (else) : (set it to) 'none'`

Answer (score 1):

its working here you can see the code http://jsfiddle.net/damian_silvera/9ym5Y/

Comment: Well, it works in your example because jsfiddle takes care of calling the code at the right time. That's not the case in the OP's code though.